# Eigenvalues of double right shift operator

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Consider the Operator S/ $S: l_2 →  l_2$ , $S(x_1,x_2,x_3,....)=(0,0,x_1,x_2,x_3,...)$
I know the right shift operator has no eigenvalues,but does this operator either?
I this for the same reason as for the right shift operator?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Consider the right-shift operator $(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots)\mapsto(0,x_{1},x_{2},\ldots)$. Suppose there exists an eigenvector $\mathbf{x}\neq0$ of the shift operator. By definition, we can find a scalar $\lambda$ such that
$$
\lambda(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots)=(0,x_{1},x_{2},\ldots).
$$
This implies that $x_{1}=0$, $\lambda x_{2}=x_{1}=0$, etc., so that
$\mathbf{x}=0$, a contradiction.

---

Consider now the double-shift $(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots)\mapsto(0,0,x_{1},x_{2},\ldots)$.
As above, suppose there exists an eigenvector $\mathbf{x}\neq0$ of the double-shift operator. By definition, we can find a scalar $\lambda$ such that
$$
\lambda(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots)=(0,0,x_{1},x_{2},\ldots).
$$
What can you conclude?

Comment: The $\lambda$ have to be at the LHS, I suppose.

Comment: Technically no since it is a field and I could be considering the inverse of the eigenvalue... ^_^ But that was definitely just a mistake.

Comment: No. You conclude that the eigenvector is again 0, contradiction. Hence, the double right shift operator has no eigenvalues.

Comment: @user1781301: that is indeed the hint I was trying to give the OP

Comment: I got that answer (Contradiction) but since I'm just starting with Spectral Theory, i wanted to be sure.
Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

If $S$ is the right shift, then you want to know if there exists $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ and $x\ne 0$ such that $S^2 x = \lambda x$. If there were such an $x$, then
$$
         (S+\sqrt{\lambda}I)(S-\sqrt{\lambda}I)x = 0.
$$
Because $(S-\sqrt{\lambda}I)x \ne 0$ (you know $S$ has no eigenvalues,) you conclude that $y=(S-\sqrt{\lambda}I)x \ne 0$ and $Sy = -\sqrt{\lambda}y$, which is a contradiction. Hence $S^2$ has no eigenvalues.